# Facebook Graph API and Insight stats don't match/incorrect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing an application using the Facebook Graph API to track metrics for our page over time, for example, number of shares of posts on the page.

We are retrieving number of shares, comments and likes from the post objects in our page feed and then summing them for our reporting period - the query is of the following form

```
{page-id}/posts?fields=shares,created_time,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&since={start-date}&until={end-date}
```

However, the numbers we are getting from this query do not match with those from the Business Manager Insights page. For example, for the month of October 2016 the Graph API count for post comments is more than twice that reported from the insights data. Furthermore, the numbers do not always match with those we get from manually counting comments etc. directly from the posts on our page.

Does anyone have an explanation for how these discrepancies might arise?

Answer (score 0):

Check this article. "Error: When gauging the total number of people who saw at least one of a Page’s posts organically over a seven-day or 28-day period, Facebook didn’t de-duplicate that audience when reporting a Page’s organic reach in its Page Insights dashboard. In other words, if someone saw a Page’s post on Monday, and then another post from that Page on Tuesday, Facebook counted that person as two people."
http://marketingland.com/heres-itemized-list-facebooks-measurement-errors-date-200663